# MacOS Terminal wait for opened program

Tags: terminal, applescript

I use an app called PDF Lightweight to compress my PDFs (since I have made very good experiences) and Thunderbird to send emails.

I want to write an AppleScript that compresses PDFs before attaching them to an email:

```
set attachment1 to "/Users/username/Desktop/Test.pdf"

do shell script "open -a " & quoted form of ("/Applications/Lightweight PDF.app") & " " & quoted form of attachment1

set email_attachment to "attachment=" & "'file://" & attachment1 & "'"
set thunderbird_bin to "/Applications/Thunderbird.app/Contents/MacOS/thunderbird-bin -compose "
set arguments to email_attachment

do shell script thunderbird_bin & quoted form of arguments & ">/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

The problem is that the original PDF will be attached before the compression finishes. I tried to work with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146093/waiting-for-do-shell-script-to-finish) but it does not work either. I suppose because I start PDF Lightweight with an "open" command which is -technically- complete even when the app is still compressing.

Any ideas how get the script waiting for the PDF compression?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround by looking on the file size now. Once the job is done the pdf should be smaller ergo it is time to move on.

```
set oldSize to text item 1 of (do shell script "du " & quoted form of ShrinkPDF)
set newSize to text item 1 of (do shell script "du " & quoted form of ShrinkPDF)

do shell script "open -a " & quoted form of ("/Applications/Lightweight PDF.app") & " " & quoted form of ShrinkPDF

set timer to 0

repeat while newSize = oldSize and timer < 6
    set newSize to text item 1 of (do shell script "du " & quoted form of ShrinkSize)
    delay 1
    set timer to timer + 1
end repeat

if newSize = oldSize then
    tell application "Lightweight PDF"
        activate
    end tell
    display dialog "This is taking a while maybe you want to quit manually..."
end if

tell application "Lightweight PDF"
quit
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how get the script waiting for the PDF compression?

While using **AppleScript**, you really do not need to use a `do shell script` *command* to open **PDF Lightweight** and process a **PDF** *file*.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will open **PDF Lightweight** and process the target **PDF** *file* and will not continue to process the remaining *code* until it has completed processing the *file*, plus a few seconds:

```
set thisPDF to "/path/to/filename.pdf"

tell application id "com.enoughpepper.lightweightpdf"
    open thisPDF's quoted form
    quit
end tell

--  # Code placed here will not run until the 
--  # PDF file has finished being processed.
```

---

If for some reason you want to use a `do shell script` *command* to open **PDF Lightweight** and process a **PDF** *file*.

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will open **PDF Lightweight** and process the target **PDF** *file* and will not continue to process the remaining *code* until it has completed processing the *file*:

```
set thisPDF to "/path/to/filename.pdf"

set shellCmd to ¬
    "ps -eo  %cpu,command | awk '/[L]ightweight PDF/{print int($1)}'"

do shell script ¬
    "open -j -b 'com.enoughpepper.lightweightpdf'" & ¬
    space & thisPDF's quoted form

delay 2
repeat while (do shell script shellCmd) is greater than 0
    delay 1
end repeat

tell application id "com.enoughpepper.lightweightpdf" to quit

--  # Code placed here will not run until the 
--  # PDF file has finished being processed.
```

In this form of the *example* **AppleScript** *code* it determines the *application* has finished processing the **PDF** *file* because it is no longer consuming **CPU** cycles. In other words, when processing the *file* is finished the `do shell script` *command* returns 0.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried your first approach but to me it seems like "open quoted form of thisPDF" does not find the document path and "open POSIX file attachment1" does find the file but not compress it. (and I do know it is possible to compress it because when I drag and drop the filr to Lightweight it works)