# How can I wait for a shell script to complete?

Tags: shell, terminal, applescript

I'm using a command-line app in an AppleScript, and I need the script to wait for the process to finish running before continuing. (And yes, I want the terminal to open and to see the app run.)

I wrote this code, based on [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20146093):

```
activate application "Terminal"
tell application "System Events"
    repeat until visible of process "Terminal" is true
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "System Events" to keystroke "app_name option"
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
        
delay 2
        
    set thePID to do shell script "app_name option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"
        
    repeat
        do shell script "ps ax | grep " & thePID & " | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'"
        if result is "" then exit repeat
        delay 2
    end repeat

-- more code...
```

Everything is working in my script, except for the part where I need it to wait for the command-line app to complete.

How can I make this work? What exactly does the part starting with `set thePID` do?

Comment: I think where the issue is, is that I'm calling the app by `keystroke` in the script, and then later basically running a separate instance of it be running `set thePID to do shell script "app_name option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"`. I assume the answer may be something like `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "app_name option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"`. But when I tried that in the terminal, it basically just showed me the process, and then it being done. ...also I'm wondering is because I have to run it with an `option`, that means the syntax needs to be different here? Maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get this to work properly, I removed:

```
set thePID to do shell script "app_name option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"
```

Then under `repeat` I changed:

```
do shell script "ps ax | grep " & thePID & " | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'"
```

to:

```
do shell script "ps ax | grep app_name | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $1 }'"
```

And now my script works as I wanted it to!

The issue was that I was calling the app by keystroke in the script, and then later basically running a separate instance of it by running `set thePID to do shell script "app_name option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"`.

I assume the answer may be something like `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "app_name option > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!"`.

I was running a second instance of the program since I was unclear about how to properly utilize the example given in that old post I linked to.

So I searched around for how to get the `PID` of running program in the terminal, and I saw that `grep app_name` was a common piece to the puzzle. Same with `ps -ax`...

So I followed my own assumption, removed the variable that called for the program to run again, and simply inserted that program's name into the `grep` part of the string replacing the variable. And it worked.

Comment: My assumption from my comment above was correct; I was running a second instance of the program since I was unclear how to properly utilize the example given in that old post I linked to.

So I searched around for how to get the PID of running program in terminal, and I saw that `grep app_name` was a common piece to the puzzle. Same with `ps -ax`... So I followed my own assumption, removed the variable that called for the program to run again, and simply inserted that program's name into the `grep` part of the string replacing the variable. And boom! It worked!